# Google Tasks API Auth

Tags: c#, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, task

I have to perform a very simple task to get all the tasks of the account Google through Google Api.

Before i started this questions i read documentation, try search to answers, read tech forums, etc

**First of all, I configured Developers Console:**
- turned ON required API's: such as Tasks API
- Create and download to my project all generic keys: WEB, SERVICE + P12 KEY, INSTALL APP
- also, Installed in project all requiered Nugets: Auth, Client, Core, Tasks.v1

**May be i wrong, but matter of great concern (Common Questions):**

**1.** Why need too many variants of keys?
Google IP is only service and it shall be necessary only one token (key)
For software there is no fundamental difference between back-end, desktop, desktop on IOS/Android/Blackberry, service,...
Software need only get/set data from/to some Google Account.
It's very confuse.

**2.** Google Developers Console - is not simple and clear tools for ordinal user which want get ability to sync with google apps.
Why Google not have simple trust Token generation for account ?

**3.** Google documentation is not fully and complex. Too many blank places: such as REST queries - not see any correct and work samples with test data and headers.
May any known - where it is ?

**Ok, let's begin practice - simple Desktop app on VS2012:**

**4.** Most of google samples said that i need to use GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker
The Code below is similar as all codes in documenation

client_secret.json - JSON files from Google Developers Console
I were try all JSON files with secret codes and also manually set secrets
But nothing, GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync try to open bad browser window and ends

```
UserCredential credential;
var stream = new FileStream(@"..." + client_secret.json, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                 GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { TasksService.Scope.Tasks },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("Tasks.Auth.Store")).Result;

                // Create the service.
                var service = new TasksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Api Project"
                });

                TaskLists results = service.Tasklists.List().Execute();
```

**What is Wrong ???**

**5.** Ок, try to use this:

```
 GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(@"..." + client_secret.json, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                    {
                        DataStore = new FileDataStore("Tasks.Auth.Store"),
                       ClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                       Scopes = new[] { TasksService.Scope.Tasks }
                   });
                }

                var result = new AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, "", "")
                    .AuthorizeAsync("user_id", CancellationToken.None).Result;

                // The data store contains the user credential, so the user has been already authenticated.
                TasksService service = new TasksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    ApplicationName = "API Project",
                    HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential
                });

                var lists = service.Tasklists.List().Execute();
```

Always - not auth.
I was try changed "user_id" - but nothing
**What is wrong ???**

**5.** Ок, try to use this:

string serviceAccountEmail = "xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

```
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"...\\key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        //var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"key.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
           new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
           {
               Scopes = new[] { TasksService.Scope.Tasks }
           }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create the service.
        var service = new TasksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "API Project",
        });



        var lists = service.Tasklists.List().Execute();

        if (lists.Items != null)
        {
            foreach (TaskList lst in lists.Items)
            {
                var title = lst.Title;
                var tasks = service.Tasks.List(lst.Id).Execute();
                if (tasks.Items != null)
                {
                    foreach (Task tsk in tasks.Items)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

!!! I have access, but not for my account.
Google return only one EMPTY enemy task list (NOT my 2 lists with many tasks in my account)

What is wrong ???

P.S. Please help. I am in deadlock. I did not expect that Google so bad.
Please, do not redirect me to another forums or topics. I all read before.

Thanks